# How to remove default "command" modifier for SwiftUI keyboardShortcut?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI has made the Command (⌘) key the default modifier for the keyboardShortcut modifier.

How can I remove the default "command" modifier for a SwiftUI keyboard shortcut?

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print(">>> Button Triggered")
    }) {
        Text("Sample Label")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("a")
}
```

Comment: Do not edit your title to add Solved. Just put your answer in the Answer field and eventually accept it. Or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a second initializer that allows to set the modifier(s), e.g.:

```
.keyboardShortcut("a", modifiers: [.command, .shift])
```

Valid `Event.Modifier`s are:
`.all`, `.command`, `.control`, `.shift`, `.numericPad`, `.capsLock`, `option`.

Any combination can be added to the array.
It is possible to choose a single ‚no modifier‘ key with an empty array like:

```
.keyboardShortcut("a", modifiers: [])
```

If you add a modifier combination not containing `.command`, be *careful that it does not interfere with text entry* in that view.

If a keyboard shortcut is equal to a system shortcut, e.g. `command + c`, it will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print(">>> Button Triggered")
    }) {
        Text("Sample Label")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("a", modifiers: [])
}
```

On macOS, the shortcut will only be triggered if the window containing the view with the shortcut is in focus.